# Txt doesn`t appear on the stage

Tags: javascript, html, add-in, addchild

Can someone pls tell me what I am doing wrong. I am trying to add text to my stage but the stage doesn`t show any text and there are no errors given. Did I do something wrong. I am adding the txt with addChild so it should appear? why is it not showing anything, it is not because of the color because I changed the color of the text.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>game</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easel.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="init();">


<canvas id=canvas width="960" height="580"></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

**javascript:**

```
var canvas;
var stage;
var score;
var bitmap;
var bmpList;
var txt;
var play;



function init() {



    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    stage = new Stage(canvas);
    score = 0;

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "imgs/stone.png";
    image.onload = maakTegenstander; 

}

function maakTegenstander(event){

    var image = event.target;
    var container = new Container();
    stage.addChild(container);


    var l = 5;
    bmpList=[]; // dit is een array
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++){ 
        bitmap = new Bitmap(image); 
        container.addChild(bitmap); 
        bitmap.name="stone"+i; 
        verwijderTegenstander(bitmap);
        bitmap.regX = bitmap.image.width/2|0;
        bitmap.regY = bitmap.image.height/2|0;
        bitmap.mouseEnabled = true;
        bmpList.push(bitmap);
    }

    txt = new Text ("Score: 0", "24px Arial", "#333");
    txt.textBaseline="top";
    txt.x = 400; 
    txt.y = 20;
    stage.addChild(txt); 
    play=true;


    Ticker.addListener(window);

}



function verwijderTegenstander(stone){

    stone.y = canvas.height - 700; 
    stone.x = canvas.width* Math.random() + 30;  

    stone.speed = (Math.random()*5)+2; 


    }

function tick(){
    if(play == true){
        var l=bmpList.length;

    }
    if (play == true){
        var l = bmpList.length;
        for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
            var bmp = bmpList[i];
            if (bmp.y < 650){ 
                bmp.y += bmp.speed;
            }else{
                //gameOver();
                console.log("game over");
            }
        }
    }
    txt.text = "Punten: "+score;
    stage.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/fXgeg/1/

I've changed two things:

For every call to easeljs module, I've added 'createjs.' e.g.

```
createjs.Stage
```

I've changed the ticker listener registration like this:

```
//Ticker.addListener(window); <- this is wrong
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
```

This way you provide the event type - **"tick"** and the function which should be called every time this event occurs - **tick()**

Comment: Heey thx! This is the error ik get now : Uncaught ReferenceError: createjs is not defined

Comment: Are you using latest easelJS file? Did you download it from createjs website?

Comment: you are doing exactly the same as me why am I getting errors and is your working. <script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.5.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have made some changes could you look at this please it is the same but now it contains a new spritesheet http://jsfiddle.net/hD2yj/                                Getting these errors now : Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){throw"SpriteSheetUtils cannot be instantiated"} has no method 'flip' spell.js:115
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'isVisible' easeljs-0.7.1.min.js:13
154
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'isVisible'

Comment: Yes, method 'flip' doesn't exist for SpriteSheetUtils. You can check this here: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/SpriteSheetUtils.html

Comment: could you mayebe help me with a solution

Comment: check out the learning resources here http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/documentation

(scoll down on this page)